# incorrect syntax CREATE PROCEDURE must be the only statement in the batch"

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi i write single stored procedure in insert update and delete but error is comming " incorrect syntax CREATE PROCEDURE must be the only statement in the batch"

once see my stored procedure

```
create Procedure  EmployeeSingle(
@EmployeeID int,
@EmployeeName varchar(20),
@Salary money,
@Gender varchar(20),
@Address varchar(20),
@Action varchar(20)=''
)
As Begin
if @Action = 'Select'
    select * from Employee 
end
if @Action = 'Insert'
begin
    insert into Employee(EmployeeID,
    EmployeeName,
    Salary ,
    Gender,
    Address 
) values (@EmployeeID,@EmployeeName,@Salary ,@Gender,@Address)
end
if @Action='Delete'
begin
    delete from Employee where EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
end
else if @Action='Update'
begin
    update Employee set 
        EmployeeName=@EmployeeName,Salary=@Salary,
        Gender=@Gender,Address=@Address   
    where EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
end
End
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a begin missing:

```
As Begin
if @Action = 'Select'
   select * from Employee 
end
```

should be:

```
As Begin
if @Action = 'Select'
begin
   select * from Employee 
end
```